# A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed for Youtube Analytics API in Explorer

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

When I try to use Youtube Analytics API in Google API Explorer, I am getting error like below,

```json
{
 "error": {
  "code": -1,
  "message": "A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed."
 }
}
```

Request URI is going like this :

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DUCTLaTj8suFpPUVC7yKGl3LA&start-date=2017-10-01&end-date=2017-10-02&metrics=views&max-results=25&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Please correct me if am going wrong.
I Enabled the ->  Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0
ids or Channel ID : MINE or My Youtube channelID i am passing.

- startdate: 2017-10-02
- enddate: 2017-10-02
- metrics: views

Answer (score 0):

- I'm not sure, but in my case, I turn off the 'UBlock' extension (block advertisement), and it works!
- I think you need to check whether your browser uses block ads or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).